# Inflate two types of .XML in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-inflate

I have gone under a lot of frustration all because of this one issue I'm having: how do I inflate different .XML files for different objects in a RecyclerView? I have done as much as I can do, such as making a ListItemType object:

```
public class ListItemType {
    public static int NOTE_VIEW = 0;
    public static int CATEGORY_VIEW = 1;
}
```

And a ListViewItem object:

```
public class ListViewItem {
    private int mType;
    private Object mObject;

    public ListViewItem(int type, Object object) {
        mType = type;
        mObject = object;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return mType;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        mType = type;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return mObject;
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        mObject = object;
    }
}
```

I'm clueless as to where I go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### RecyclerView Implement

First of all you have to add/create to/your `Model` type that indicates the your `Model` type and to know which layout to inflate:

**MyModel.java**

```
public class MyModel {
    public enum ModelTypes {
        TYPE_1,
        TYPE_2
    }
    // your model members ^^^

    ModelTypes type;
}
```

Now you have to create your `ViewHolder`, I suggest to create a parent `ViewHolder` class and extends your model types with sub classes.

**MyHolder.java**

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // must have the ViewHolder default constructor
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public static MyHolder inflateViewByType(MyModel.ModelTypes type, 
                                            LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_1:
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_type_1, parent, false);
                return new MyHolderType1(view);
            break;
            case TYPE_2:
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_type_2, parent, false);
                return new MyHolderType2(view);
            break;
        }
        // Model type not supported
        return null;
    }
}
```

Create your `ViewHolder` types, in my example i have only two types.

**MyHolderType1.java**

```
public class MyHolderType1 extends MyHolder {

    // layout members

    public MyHolderType1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // init your layout members by for layout_type_1 by itemView.findViewById(...)
    }
}
```

**MyHolderType2.java**

```
public class MyHolderType2 extends MyHolder {

    // layout members

    public MyHolderType2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // init your layout members by for layout_type_2 by itemView.findViewById(...)
    }
}
```

Until now you only create the `ViewHolder` types to implement the `RecyclerView`. 
`RecyclerView` must have an `Adapter` that extends the default `RecyclerView.Adapter`, to do this we have to create a new class and extends the `RecyclerView.Adapter` with our `ViewHolder`.

**MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    private List<MyModel> mData;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(@NonNull List<MyModel> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        MyModel.ModelTypes type = MyModel.ModelTypes.values()[viewType];
        return MyHolder.inflateViewByType(type, layoutInflater, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

        MyModel model = mData.get(position);
        switch (model.type) {
            case TYPE_1:
                setupViewType1((MyHolderType1) holder, model);
                break;
            case TYPE_2:
                setupViewType2((MyHolderType2) holder, model);
                break;
        }
    }

    // to update the adapter data without reinitialize it
    public void updateData(@NonNull List<MyModel> newData) {
        mData = newData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setupViewType1(MyHolderType1 holder, MyModel model) {

        // do what you want with your views in layout_type_1
    }

    private void setupViewType2(MyHolderType2 holder, MyModel model) {

        // do what you want with your views in layout_type_2
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mData.get(position).type.ordinal();
    }
}
```

Keep going, we almost done.
Now we have to initialize the `RecyclerView` in our activity, and set the an instance of `MyRecyclerViewAdapter` to it.
To this we have find out `RecyclerView` in and xml by calling `findViewById(...)`, and then set the `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView`, after all we set the adapter with our data.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    // ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);


        // init your views
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);


        // here you can pull or generate your recycler view list data
        List<MyModel> data = getData();
        MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(data);


        // set layout manager to the recycler view (Required)
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
                                                        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        // set the adapter to the recycler view (Required)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // ....
}
```